# how to debug windows service start-up code in c,not c#

Tags: c, windows, debugging, windows-services, startup

everyone

I want to know how to debug the windows service start-up code in C.there are several questions like this but in C# but they are not what I need.
So far,I can only attach to process to debug.Now I want to debug the main() function,how to do? The more detailed,the better.

Thanks so much.

My codes are below.

**main function:**

```
void main()
{   
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[2];
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceName = "MemoryStatus";  
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain; //ServiceMain
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;

    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable);
}
```

**ServiceMain Function:**

```
void ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv)
{        
    //...some codes....

    hStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler("MemoryStatus",(LPHANDLER_FUNCTION)ControlHandler);

    //...some codes....

    //the worker loop of a service
    while(ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
    {
        char buffer[10];        
        sprintf(buffer,"login...");
        int result = WriteToLog(buffer);        
        if (result)
        {
             ReportStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED,-1);
             return;
        }
        Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }
    return;
}
```

and **control handle function:**

```
void ControlHandler(DWORD request)
{
    switch(request)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
        WriteToLog("Monitoring stopped.");
        //...Report Status to SCM code....
        return;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
        WriteToLog("Monitoring stopped.");
        //...Report Status to SCM code....
        return;
    default:
        break;
    }
//...Report Status to SCM code....
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two different ways to debug a windows service from its start. Both are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

My preferred one consists of using a remote debugger session that starts with a service (you may use `ntsd` from Windows Debugging Tool). There is a special mechanism in Windows that enables you to hijack a process based on its image name (Image File Execution Options). Below you can find a content of a .reg file that will setup this debugger for you (change the path to the one where you have Debugging tools installed):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\svchost.exe]
"Debugger"="\"C:\\tools\\debugging\\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\\ntsd.exe\" -server npipe:pipe=svcpipe -noio"
```

Next step would be to attach to this session using user-mode debugger:

```
windbg -remote "npipe:pipe=svcpipe,server=localhost"
```

and you are ready to debug. Remember to remove the registry settings before you reboot your machine, otherwise windows will hang with a black screen :)

Comment: It is easier to use the GFlags.exe tool to set and unset the windows registry for you. It is quick, and allows you to specify everything you need to. Just start it, click on "Image File" tab, type in the name of the image in the image text box, hit TAB, and then go down to the debugger line. Check the debugger box and type in the command line for the debugger, click ok.
Unsetting is very easy. Go uncheck the check box by Debugger.

Comment: The article linked from this answer was a great asset. I would like to add that you must restart the system after changing the ServicesPipeTimeout registry value for the new value to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

OK,two ways:
First,we can sleep the service process at the beginning of code. like this:

```
main()
{
    sleep(10);
    .....
}
```

and then attach to the service process, the debugger will stop at the position of breakpoint as we have 10 seconds to wait.

Second,we can use `_ASSERT(FALSE)` or `DebugBreak()` function at the beginning of code.